# Try/Catch or if?

Tags: python, if-statement, try-catch

Is it better to use:

```
var = "Test"
dictionary = {"test": "test", "test2": "test2"}
try:
    var2 = dictionary[var]

except KeyError:
    pass
```

or:

```
var = "test"
if (var == "test" or var == "test2"):
    dosomething()
```

Which of these is the better way to go?
This code is designed to prevent the user from entering a string that
is not valid.

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. Sometimes asking for forgiveness (using `try`) is better, sometimes asking for permission (using `if`) is faster.

Comment: See [Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/175655)

Comment: And on that note, with those two terms you can [search for more questions on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+forgiveness+permission).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'd honestly say neither of those approaches is ideal.  The first one uses a `dict` for a side-effect and is needlessly verbose; the second is very clunky to write and read when there are lots of `or`s strung together.

I'd recommend using the `in` operator and a `set`:

```
if var in {'test','test2'}:
    #do something
```

In your first example, you're using a `dict` as a `set` stand-in, you should just use a proper `set`.  You want to use a `dict` when you have an actual mapping of keys to values.

Comment: Any particular reason you have used a set instead of a tuple? The later is more efficient (if it doesn't contain a million elements) and looks less weird.

Comment: @siegfriedgevatter Set membership tests are O(1), tuple is O(n).  For n=2 that obviously doesn't matter, but the overhead of creating either is negligible.  Also, in python 3, set literals are optimized away at compile time, and are even faster.  Either way I don't see how a set literal looks "weird", it is a declaration of constants.

Comment: Asymptotic complexity hardly matters for a hard-coded list of a few items, the constant factor is more important. Not that execution time of either option is a concern at all, I just (initially) pointed it out in case you were using the set as some sort of optimization.

Didn't know about the optimization in Python 3, thanks for the information. Do you have some link where I can read more about it?

As for the weird, I've just never seen it before (while "if x in (a, b, c)" is quite common).

Comment: @SiegfriedGevatter see here: [what's new in python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations).

Comment: OK, I'm still a Python 2 guy :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `var` value to be just one of the set, use this pattern:

```
var = 'test'
allowed = 'one', 'two', 'three', 'test'

if var in allowed:
    doSomething()
else:
    doSomethingElse()
```

For the dictionary you can modify the condition like this:

```
if var in dictionary.keys():
```

Comment: @Veedrac but it works as `var in dictionary.values()` then, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope. `(True in {True: False}) == (True in {True: False}.keys())` evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with the `try`/`except` mainly because *you don't have to explicitly list all of the accepted values*. You could just use `if var in dictionary.keys()`, but why not just a built-in dictionary method?

```
value = dictionary.get(var) # if it does not find var in the dictionary, returns None
if value is None:
    doSomething()
```

Of course, this does not work properly when you have a dictionary like such: `{var: None}`; it would return `None` regardless of whether or not it can be found in the dictionary. But if you are not expecting any `NoneType` objects as values, then this is the way to go :).